# number of times 'velocity_dif' is bigger than 0 per user

Tags: python, difference

I have a dataframe which contains the column velocity_dif and I need to know how many times velocity_dif is bigger than 0 grouped per user.
This is my code until now:

```
df_trials_clean['total_path'] = np.sqrt((df_paths_clean['x'])**2+ 
(df_paths_clean['y'])**2).groupby(["user",'trial']).max()
df_trials_clean['velocity'] = df_trials_clean['total_path'] / df_trials_clean['total_time']
df_trials_clean['velocity_dif'] = df_trials_clean['velocity'].diff()
```

I tried:

```
df_1k_c = df_trials_clean['velocity_dif'] > 0
df_1k = df_trials_clean[df_1k_c]
df_1k['user'] = df_users['user']
df_1k.set_index('user')
```

Which gives me the positive values but not how many times per user.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are various ways how to do it. This one is surely not the most concise one but hopefully easy to understand.

Let's say that you have a dataframe `df` with (among others) a column of velocities like this:

```
   user velocity
0   A   10
1   A   11
2   B   9
3   A   12
4   B   4
5   A   13
6   A   9
7   C   1
8   B   6
9   B   8
```

Take a set of all users:

```
users = set(df['user'])
users
>> {'C', 'B', 'A'}
```

and define a function that calculates the number of improvements per user:

```
def impr(df, user):
    # take only entries of this particular user:
    aux = df[df['user'] == user].copy()  
    aux['velocity_dif'] = aux['velocity'].diff()
    return sum(aux['velocity_dif'] > 0)  # counts True as 1, False as 0
```

Now you can make a dataframe showing improvements per user like this:

```
improvements = pd.DataFrame([[user, impr(df, user)] for user in users], 
                            columns = ['user', 'nr improvements'])
improvements
```

For the input as shown above, this would give

```
   user nr improvements
0   C   0
1   B   2
2   A   3
```

As a oneliner (much more concise but definitely not easy to read = not preferable), this gives the same result:

```
improvements = pd.DataFrame([[user, sum(df[df['user'] == user]['velocity'].diff() > 0)] for user in users], columns = ['user', 'nr improvements'])
```